# Why was the site "read-only" for a while?

Tags: support

I noticed one and a half hours ago that the site was in a "read-only" state for some time for some sort of "maintenance". Was it just periodic maintenance? If so, what is the maintenance schedule? If not, what exactly was wrong?

Comment: They periodically make the site read only so the mods can conive evil plots in secret! >:D

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://twitter.com/StackStatus would be the place to check. Assuming it was ~7 hours ago it looks like there was some testing going on

Comment: At the time I posted this question, I was in an environment in which Twitter was blocked. http://stackstatus.net/ didn't show anything about it, either.